# Print items from a list using index of a for loop in jinja code

Tags: html, django, jinja2

```
{% for index in length %}
 {{index}}
 <img src={{image_url.index}} width="200" height="250">
{% endfor %}
```

length contains number list from 0 to 38 **i.e.** [0,1,2,......38]
The image_url contains the list of image urls that I want show in my webpage. The **{{index}}** code run properly and show the index number from 0 to 38. But when I try to display image using **{{image_url.index}}** no image is displayed. Is there an solution for this?

Comment: If image_url is a list you could do `{{ image_url[index] }}` in jinja2

Answer (score 0):

Django does not convert your `index` to this value for getting the image_url corresponding.

Why do you not loop on image_url ?

```
{% for url in image_url %}
 {{forloop.counter0}}
 <img src={{url}} width="200" height="250">
{% endfor %}
```

Else, you have to create a custom filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/):

```
# templatetags/extras.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_item(array, key):
    return array[key]

# in template
{% load extras %}

{{image_url|get_item:index}}
```

Comment: actually i wanted to print data of other lists too like
`{{item.index}}`
`{{price.index}}` 
and looping on image url would only give me the content of image url list
is there any alternative for this? 
my code looks like this

  `{% for index in length %}
            <br>
            <img src={{url.index}} width="200" height="250">
            <br>
            <br>
            <h6>For {{name.index}}</h6>
            <p>{{category.index}}</p>
            <p>{{price.index}}</p>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: i have edited my post for other solution with a custom template filter

Comment: you can validate my answer if it is ok ;)